# statsd_exporter: error: unknown short flag '-s', try --help in Istio

Tags: kubernetes-helm, istio

**Version of Helm and Kubernetes:**

Kubernetes: 1.11.3

Helm: v2.10.0

Istio: 0.2.13-chart4

**What happened:**

All the Istio containers deployed successfully except "Istio-mixer".
statsd_exporter container doesn't start. Viewing the pod with kubectl get pods I see that the pod is getting into a CrashLoopBackOff state.

**What you expected to happen:**

Would like to see the pod start up successfully without interruptions.

**How to reproduce it (as minimally and precisely as possible):**

helm install incubator/istio --version 0.2.13-chart4

helm upgrade istio incubator/istio --reuse-values --set istio.install=true --version 0.2.13-chart4

Comment: could you attach some logs: `kubectl describe pod Istio-mixer-podname`, in field events.

Comment: @NickRak Thanks for your comment. I am getting this error because I was using latest version of Istio instead of stable version. So, I have resolved this issue by using Istio stable version. Now, it is successfully working.